# IndexOutOfBound Exception throwing Android

Tags: java, android, exception

i have make one android application in that data is coming from server so it's time consuming process so i have created one progress dialog box..

below is my code

```
  @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (placesListItems != null)
        placesListItems.clear();
    new LoadPlaces().execute();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (pDialog != null)
        pDialog.dismiss();
}


  class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Search</b><br/>Loading Places..."));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }



  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        GooglePlaces googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

        try {
            double radius = 1000; // 10000 meters

            // get nearest places
            if (query != null) {
                nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(lat, lon, radius, query);
                if (nearPlaces != null) {

                    for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                        reference = p.reference;
                        lat = p.geometry.location.lat;
                        lon = p.geometry.location.lng;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            String types = "bar|restaurant|night_club|gym|health|food|shopping_mall|hospital";

            if (reference != null) {
                PlaceDetails placeDetails = googlePlaces.getPlaceDetails(reference);
                if (placeDetails != null) {
                    String status = placeDetails.status;

                    // check place deatils status
                    // Check for all possible status
                    if (status.equals("OK")) {
                        if (placeDetails.result != null) {
                            lat = placeDetails.result.geometry.location.lat;
                            lon = placeDetails.result.geometry.location.lng;
                            nearDeals = googlePlaces.search(lat, lon, radius, types);
```

In below code if i press home button or screen goes of during fetching data from server (You can say progress dialog box is running) and if i come back to my application i got an error ARRAY INDEX OUT OF BOUND

```
                    // int total = ;
                            for (int i = nearDeals.results.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                // Log.i("WHAT THE HELL",nearPlaces.results.get(i).name);
                                if (getResult(nearDeals.results.get(i).name, nearDeals.results.get(i).geometry.location.lat,
                                        nearDeals.results.get(i).geometry.location.lng) == 0) {
                                    // nearDeals.results.add(nearPlaces.results.get(i));
                                    nearDeals.results.remove(i);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

below is logcat

```
  09-25 18:23:13.429: W/System.err(4375): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 15, size is 15
  09-25 18:23:13.429: W/System.err(4375):   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
  09-25 18:23:13.429: W/System.err(4375):   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
  09-25 18:23:13.429: W/System.err(4375):   at com.eheuristics.android.diegodeals.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:204)
  09-25 18:23:13.429: W/System.err(4375):   at com.eheuristics.android.diegodeals.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
  09-25 18:23:13.429: W/System.err(4375):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
  09-25 18:23:13.439: W/System.err(4375):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
  09-25 18:23:13.439: W/System.err(4375):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
  09-25 18:23:13.439: W/System.err(4375):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
  09-25 18:23:13.439: W/System.err(4375):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  09-25 18:23:13.439: W/System.err(4375):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

if i do not press home key, or do not screen goes off during progress dialog box is running then everything is working fine

//After getting solution from all of you, i have done blow like all suggest but i got another error like blow

```
    LoadPlaces ob;


    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (placesListItems != null)
        placesListItems.clear();
    ob.execute();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(ob!=null)
    if(ob.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
       ob.cancel(true);
    }

    if (pDialog != null)
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

then i got error like below

```
   09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.eheuristics.android.diegodeals/com.eheuristics.android.diegodeals.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2241)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:380)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at com.eheuristics.android.diegodeals.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:137)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
  09-25  18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
  09-25  18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
  09-25 18:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):   ... 10 more
```

Comment: Can you point out line 204 in MainActivity.java? Your `neardeals.results` List size is 0, which means it doesn't have an index, which means it's not being filled.

Comment: how can you say that list size is zero if it is zero than i will not get exception like Invalid index 15, size is 15

Comment: Please don't curse in your code (;_;)

Comment: 204 No. line is                                                                      if (getResult(nearDeals.results.get(i).name, nearDeals.results.get(i).geometry.location.lat,
           nearDeals.results.get(i).geometry.location.lng) == 0) {

Comment: is nearDeals.results thread-safe? i.e. may the size change while iterating thru it?

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the asynctask every time you show your activity. So, you should cancel the task when exiting (AsyncTask.cancel(true)), or check if it is still running in the onResume method.

Comment: ya you are right i am starting asynctask every time because if user goes back to previous activity he should get new refresh data

Comment: ok, but every time you do "new LoadPlaces().execute();", you have the last asynctask and the new one executing at the same time!

Comment: first of all thanks, i have changed code but still get another error

Answer (score 0):

In the cases where you get the error onResume() gets called again, starting a new AsyncTask. Now you have multiple AsyncTask simultanously accessing and altering the size of nearDeals.results (you call remove on it). When one asyncTask removes an item from the list, the second asyncTask may run into the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds since the list size has changed.

EDIT: It's actually not the removal of an item, but that you set a new instance of the list in googlePlaces.search and this list may have a different size than the one used by the old asynctask.

Solution: call cancel on your running async tasks in onPause (or in onResume before starting 
the new task)

Comment: first of all thanks, i have changed code but still get another error

Comment: you need to create a new instance of the AsyncTask in onResume, you cannot re-start a previously canceled task.

Comment: Ya but still same error occur if i press home button and again come back 2 to 3 times than error will happen :(

Comment: which one? the illegalstate or the indexoutofbounds?

Comment: if i understand your code correctly nearDeals is currently a member variable of your Activity. Maybe it would make sense to create a local variable in the async task first, then iterate thru the results manipulating the list and only after you finished set the new list to the global member variable. that should remove most of the side effects with the simultaneous access.